# La vista previa no se mueve en brackets

Tags: html, html5, ide, brackets

Estoy empezando a escribir en `HTML` y estoy utilizando e editor de texto `Brackets` por sus múltiples funciones que me son de gran utilidad.

Pero la que mas me hizo instalar el programa fue la vista previa dinámica para no tener que guardar y ver cada mínimo cambio que hacía en el código.

El problema es que la vista previa no me resalta los textos cuando los estoy editando ni me cambia un texto en la pagina cuando estoy modificándolo en el código fuente, en resumen no es dinámica la vista previa.

Ya intenté reinstalando el programa y aun no encuentro solución. Y en google no he encontrado un caso similar o igual al mio.

Comment: No he usado nunca ese editor , no se si en este [link](https://cloudconfusing.com/2019/03/22/brackets-live-preview-is-not-working-how-to-fix-it/) puedes encontrar informacion relacionada . De todas formas siempre puedes probar otros editores... :)

Comment: No sé cual es el problema pero te puedo recomendar Visual Studio Code y desde ahí puedes instalar la extensión "Live server" desde la misma plataforma, y ahí únicamente tendrás que presionar control + s y ya se actualizará. Si necesitas más ayuda no dudes en preguntar.